# Adding calendar appointments with Exchange web services and PHP

Tags: php, exchangewebservices

I have an interesting conundrum here and I'm hoping someone can at least tell me if my possible solution is actually possible.

I have a PHP site on which I am creating a page to create and track responses to exchange calendar appointments and their notifications.

The user adds all the pertinent information on the event and saves it, the event info is stored in the db and the email is created and sent out to the recipients. I am writing the ics code, so when the recipients receive it, it looks like an appointment notification as though it was sent from an exchange client.  Up to this point everything is golden.

But the idea is to use an email where its sole purpose is to track these responses and events. Then I will have a service using EWS setup on a separate server, as the site is on a LAMP server, that will periodically check the events on this address for responses, and update the mysql database with the reponses so they can be displayed on the events' page.

The problem is when I create the event and send out the emails from PHP, there is no event created for the host address, so when a recipient selects a response option (accepted, declined, tentative), the host receives nothing as the response is to an event it doesn't have.

Is there a way to create the event through PHP?

Or could I add a method to the service I already have that will create the event on the host address and call it from PHP?

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote: participants reactions to sent invitation are useless because organizer of an appointment (your event) does not have any info about this appointment.

What you could do is add creation of an appointment in host's calendar in ExchangeServer regarding an event that user created with your PHP webpage. Invitations will be send automatically when you save an appointment with proper save method and if you make a subscription for host's calendar folder events (EWS subscription events not yours) and you will check it periodically you can update your record with participants' responses.

You can create appointment like this:

```
Appointment app = new Appointment(_service);
app.Start = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
app.End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2);
app.Subject = "Test appointment";
app.RequiredAttendees.Add("joe@example.com");
app.RequiredAttendees.Add("tom@example.com");
app.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

And to make a subscription for calendar folder:

```
var subscription =  _service.SubscribeToPullNotifications(new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Calendar }, 5, null, EventType.Created, EventType.Deleted, EventType.Modified, EventType.FreeBusyChanged);
```

Code above creates subscription for event regarding Calendar with timeout 5 minutes (so subscription will be removed from server if you don't check it at least one time per 5 minutes) and subscription will contain queue of events regarding items that was created, modified, deleted, or had their free/busy status changed.

To query a subscription for events you do something like this:

```
    var events = subscription.GetEvents();
    if (events.AllEvents.Count > 0)
    {
       foreach (var itemEvent in events.ItemEvents)
       {
           switch (itemEvent.EventType)
           {
               case EventType.Created:
                    break;
               case EventType.Modified:
                    break;
               case EventType.Copied:
                    break;
               case EventType.FreeBusyChanged:
                    break;
           }
       }
   }
```

And you can update your database when you get event type for items that you are interested in.